# how to print ptype of polymorphic objects in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, polymorphism

Consider the simple class shown below:

[image]

When we print the ptype of either b or d in a gdb session, it will print the base class(as expected).

But logically it is incorrect. Is there any way to print the actual type of objects(based on the polymorphic behaviour)?

E.g:-

```
$ ptype b

type = class Base {
  public:
    virtual void display(void) const;
}

$ ptype d

type = class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    virtual void display(void) const;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `set print object on`, then your output will look like this:

```
(gdb) set print object on 
(gdb) ptype b
type = /* real type = Base * */
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void display(void) const;
} *
(gdb) ptype d
type = /* real type = Derived * */
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void display(void) const;
} *
```

After setting `print object on` printing the value of the object will change, so now you get:

```
(gdb) p b
$1 = (Base *) 0x416eb0
(gdb) p d
$2 = (Derived *) 0x416ed0
```

Answer (score 0):

simply make a function in base as follows

```
**virtual void function(){
 cout << "base class function";
}**
```

and in derived class make the function as folllows:

```
**void function(){
cout << "derived class";
}**
```

You'll achieve the polymorphic behaviour and will have the correct output as well!

Comment: I am able to achieve polymorphic behaviour but when I try to print the type information in a gdb sesion, I am getting the output mentioned in the post.